# Passing parameter to days.ago (Rails 5)

Tags: time, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have the following method and I am using 5.days.ago method in rails. It feels funny to do what I am doing since I am calling `days.ago` on the object `days_posting_delayed`.

Is there a better method I can use than this? One where I pass the parameter into it instead of calling a method on it?

```
def with_delay(days_posting_delayed)
  update { relation.where("posting.created_at < (?)", days_posting_delayed.days.ago) }
end
```

Comment: can you tell me what does "days_posting_delayed" method?

Comment: It’s just a parameter, an integer, 1,5,30

Comment: you want data of 5 days before?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its Funny, but there is not other method than it. 
but you can also use rails other methods

```
EX:- DateTime.now - 5.days
     DateTime.now - 2.hours
     DateTime.now - 6.months

def with_delay(days_posting_delayed)
  update { relation.where("posting.created_at < (?)", DateTime.now - days_posting_delayed.days) }
end
```